# 403 error when making an SQL query for a Fusion Table

Tags: json, jsonp, google-fusion-tables, http-status-code-403

I've been trying to migrate my project to new API, but I get the following error when trying out an SQL query such as the following:

[https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT * FROM 1KxVV0wQXhxhMScSDuqr-0Ebf0YEt4m4xzVplKd4&key=myKey](https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT%20%2a%20FROM%201KxVV0wQXhxhMScSDuqr-0Ebf0YEt4m4xzVplKd4&key=myKey)

Here is what gets returned:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured"
 }
}
```

The following query does work, though:
https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/tables/1bTX-w0Lt6nT8jq4R0q2pwFvuN_X5iPDOKHWFhw/columns?key=myKey

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For me, both queries work when I enter my API key. Did you already fix the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You also need to make sure the Fusion Table is Exportable.

```
File → About this table
       → Edit table information
         → Check the "Allow download" checkbox
```

Answer (score 2):

I started a new project in the API console and using the new API key fixed it, strangely.