# Google Map with Fusion Table data not displaying map markers

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I'm trying to create a Google Map that loads map data from a Fusion Table, with custom map markers, based on the solution shown here:
http://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables/issues/detail?id=69#c107

My version of this code is working to display the map, and it also seems like the json data request from the Fusion Table is successful, but no markers are displaying on the map.

Can someone suggest what I'm doing wrong?

Page is here:
http://clorentzen.com/queensbrewery/fusiontable.html

Thanks!

More info:
The table:
https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1coED7p2uvV31pMNMPhHsrPRxZCfZv4b9LvkvrCc

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Fusion Table version of QB on draft info</title>
    <style>
    body {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    #map-canvas {
        height: 500px;
        width: 600px;
    }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var map;
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var DEFAULT_ICON_URL = 'http://clorentzen.com/queensbrewery/qb_maps.png';

    // EDIT: change this key to your own from the Google APIs Console
    // https://code.google.com/apis/console/
    var apiKey = 'AIzaSyAlluI5j2piL1x7OK8dOiZRreO3L6VCZSQ';

    // EDIT: Specify the table with location data and icon URLs
    var tableID = '1coED7p2uvV31pMNMPhHsrPRxZCfZv4b9LvkvrCc';

    // Create variables for the columns you need to retrieve from the table
    // EDIT this list as needed, then find and edit two places below.
    var latitudeColumn = 'LATITUDE';
    var longitudeColumn = 'LONGITUDE';
    var iconUrlColumn = 'ICON';
    var venueColumn = 'BAR';
    var addressColumn = 'ADDRESS';
    var neighborhoodColumn = 'NEIGHBORHOOD';
    var regionColumn = 'REGION';


    function createMarker (coordinate, url, content) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: coordinate,
            icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(url)
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
            infoWindow.setPosition(coordinate);
            infoWindow.setContent(content);
            infoWindow.open(map);
        });
    };

    function fetchData() {

        // Construct a query to get data from the Fusion Table
        // EDIT this list to include the variables for columns named above
        var query = 'SELECT '
        + latitudeColumn + ','
        + longitudeColumn + ','
        + iconUrlColumn + ','
        + venueColumn + ','
        + addressColumn + ','
        + neighborhoodColumn + ','
        + regionColumn + ' FROM '
        + tableID;
        var encodedQuery = encodeURIComponent(query);

        // Construct the URL
        var url = ['https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query'];
        url.push('?sql=' + encodedQuery);
        url.push('&key=' + apiKey);
        url.push('&callback=?');

        // Send the JSONP request using jQuery
        $.ajax({
            url: url.join(''),
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: onDataFetched
        });
    }

    function onDataFetched(data) {
        var rows = data['rows'];
        var iconUrl;
        var content;
        var coordinate;


        // Copy each row of data from the response into variables.
        // Each column is present in the order listed in the query.
        // Starting from 0.
        // EDIT this if you've changed the columns, above.
        for (var i in rows) {
            coordinate = new google.maps.LatLng(rows[i][0],rows[i][1]);
            iconUrl = rows[i][2];
            content = "<strong>" + rows[i][3] + "</strong><br>" + rows[i][4] + "<br>" + rows[i][5] + ", " + rows[i][6] + "<br>";

            if (iconUrl) {   // ensure not empty
                createMarker(coordinate, iconUrl, content);
            } else {
                createMarker(coordinate, DEFAULT_ICON_URL, content);
            }
        }
    }

    function initialize() {

        fetchData();  // begin retrieving data from table, and put it on the map

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.7,-73.8),
            zoom: 13,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code in your question, not only a link, then we can help even if you link doesn't work (as is the case with yours).  And for FusionTables questions a link to the table is also useful.

Answer (score 2):

That error (message: "Access Not Configured") is due to having a key that doesn't have the correct referrers (at least when I added a correct key, it works for me).

The real issue is that you have the latitude and longitude reversed, so the markers appear in Antarctica.

[working example (with my key)](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_FusionTables_queryForMarkers.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Fusion Table version of QB on draft info</title>
    <style>
    body {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    #map-canvas {
        height: 500px;
        width: 600px;
    }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var map;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var DEFAULT_ICON_URL = 'http://clorentzen.com/queensbrewery/qb_maps.png';

    // EDIT: change this key to your own from the Google APIs Console
    // https://code.google.com/apis/console/
    var apiKey = 'AIzaSyCxitB5jQcw7weQdg9MqBRfxr6mj81wT7I';

    // EDIT: Specify the table with location data and icon URLs
    var tableID = '1coED7p2uvV31pMNMPhHsrPRxZCfZv4b9LvkvrCc';

    // Create variables for the columns you need to retrieve from the table
    // EDIT this list as needed, then find and edit two places below.
    var latitudeColumn = 'LATITUDE';
    var longitudeColumn = 'LONGITUDE';
    var iconUrlColumn = 'ICON';
    var venueColumn = 'BAR';
    var addressColumn = 'ADDRESS';
    var neighborhoodColumn = 'NEIGHBORHOOD';
    var regionColumn = 'REGION';


    function createMarker (coordinate, url, content) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: coordinate,
            icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(url)
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
            infoWindow.setPosition(coordinate);
            infoWindow.setContent(content);
            infoWindow.open(map);
        });
    bounds.extend(coordinate);
    };

    function fetchData() {

        // Construct a query to get data from the Fusion Table
        // EDIT this list to include the variables for columns named above
        var query = 'SELECT '
        + latitudeColumn + ','
        + longitudeColumn + ','
        + iconUrlColumn + ','
        + venueColumn + ','
        + addressColumn + ','
        + neighborhoodColumn + ','
        + regionColumn + ' FROM '
        + tableID;
        var encodedQuery = encodeURIComponent(query);

        // Construct the URL
        var url = ['https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query'];
        url.push('?sql=' + encodedQuery);
        url.push('&key=' + apiKey);
        url.push('&callback=?');

        // Send the JSONP request using jQuery
        $.ajax({
            url: url.join(''),
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: onDataFetched
        });
    }

    function onDataFetched(data) {
        var rows = data['rows'];
        var iconUrl;
        var content;
        var coordinate;


        // Copy each row of data from the response into variables.
        // Each column is present in the order listed in the query.
        // Starting from 0.
        // EDIT this if you've changed the columns, above.
        for (var i in rows) {
            coordinate = new google.maps.LatLng(rows[i][1],rows[i][0]);
            iconUrl = rows[i][2];
            content = "<strong>" + rows[i][3] + "</strong><br>" + rows[i][4] + "<br>" + rows[i][5] + ", " + rows[i][6] + "<br>";

            if (iconUrl) {   // ensure not empty
                createMarker(coordinate, iconUrl, content);
            } else {
                createMarker(coordinate, DEFAULT_ICON_URL, content);
            }
        }
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }

    function initialize() {

        fetchData();  // begin retrieving data from table, and put it on the map

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.7,-73.8),
            zoom: 13,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. It is indeed the reversal of latitude and longitude that was the problem. Working great now.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you don't get any useful data in `onDataFetched` function. Log of `data` shows `error` object with:

```
code: 403
...
message: "Access Not Configured"
```

Possible reason could be non-exportable table. See answer in [403 error when making an SQL query for a Fusion Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273278/403-error-when-making-an-sql-query-for-a-fusion-table)

Comment: Thanks, just checked this, and I do have the "Reuse access" set to "allow downloads."