# Cannot insert into Fusion Tables from another account?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-fusion-tables

So I'm trying to insert into my Fusion Table from a script located on a google scripts but from a different account and different computer. The account does not know about the Fusion Table and when it tries to run the script that needs to insert the value, it returns a "Forbidden" error

Here's my code to store an e-mail entry

```
function registration(tableId) {

  var email = "test";
  var sql = "INSERT INTO " + tableId + " (Email) VALUES (\'" + email + "\');";
  var query = FusionTables.Query.sql(sql);
}
```

It always results in a forbidden if I try to insert it from another drive account. But the weird thing is that a

```
SELECT * FROM tableId;
```

Works just fine and pulls everything from the table. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

With that "Forbidden" error, I would suggest that you check these two things:

1. Please make sure that you have already enabled [Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced). As noted in [Fusion Tables Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/fusion-tables),

   > This is an advanced service that must be enabled before use.
2. Secondly, please make sure that your Fusion Table is exportable. As provided by @WillemLabu in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13233584), please check the following:

   > File → About this table
   >         → Edit table information
   >           → Check the "Allow download" checkbox

You may also check the given solution in [Fix “403 Forbidden” Error with Google Fusion Table REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32978998/fix-403-forbidden-error-with-google-fusion-table-rest-api).